# Django crispy-forms field_class not working as expected

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I'm building simple from with `crispy-forms` but `field-class` attribute doesn't work as expected.

**Form**

```
class ArrivalForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ArrivalForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'arrival-form'
        self.helper.form_class = ''
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.form_action = ''
        self.helper.field_class = 'form-control'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            Div('passenger_name', css_class='col-md-6'),
            Div('passenger_lastname', css_class='col-md-6'),  
            css_class='row'), 
        )

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))

    passenger_name = forms.CharField(
        label = "Firstname:",
        max_length = 80,
        required = True,
    )

    passenger_lastname = forms.CharField(
        label = "Lastname:",
        max_length = 80,
        required = True,
    )
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<form id="arrival-form" method="post" name="arrival-form">
    <input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" type="hidden" value=
    "akxd0BVQrwaHbHr4FLjaDLz72BUUN9rQ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="control-group" id="div_id_passenger_name">
                <label class="control-label requiredField" for=
                "id_passenger_name">Firstname:<span class=
                "asteriskField">*</span></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="textinput textInput" id="id_passenger_name"
                    maxlength="80" name="passenger_name" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="control-group" id="div_id_passenger_lastname">
                <label class="control-label requiredField" for=
                "id_passenger_lastname">Lastname:<span class=
                "asteriskField">*</span></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="textinput textInput" id=
                    "id_passenger_lastname" maxlength="80" name=
                    "passenger_lastname" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-id-submit" name="submit"
        type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Problem**
I'm expecting `input` fields to have `form-control` class added automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `field_class` property only works if you are using the `bootstrap3` template pack (and not the default `bootstrap` pack). Check you have the following setting defined:

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
```

In fact once you set the right template back it will insert a `form-control` class by default, so you don't need to set it manually at all.